Single Outlets Failing
I have three (so far) outlets that have no power. Three different locations through the home. I have checked the breakers and all seem to be fine. All worked within the last month or so. Rooms with bad outlets have fully functional lights through wall switches. None of the outlets are GFI, although two of them are in bathrooms.

If it's in the bathroom, is it chained off another GFCI instead? My last house had two bathrooms that shared a GFCI, so when it failed both bathrooms lost wall power.

Bathrooms since early 90s had GFCI protection, so if newer than the 90s, there should be GFCI somewhere.  Might just be a push in/or a loose connection that failed also.  Fine breakers will read 120v with a meter.  More sure than looking fine.

I would pull receps and ensure you don't have loose stabs if wired as so.  Also ensure these are not in  GFCI controlled circuit as well, The first GFCI may just be located im a different area.

Garage and outside can be common locations for the 'master' GFCI.
